# Android: Paint with Hardware Accelerated

Tags: android

I'm implementing a painting app with the erase option. I'm doing it using PorterDuff.Mode.Clear but I have two different behaviors while erasing, depending on the hardwareAccelerated flag.

Screenshot during painting: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/194622/Screenshot_2012-12-13-16-36-33.png

The final result is the same but this "black trace" only occurs during erasing with hardwareAccelerated on.

Any suggestion besides disabling hardware acceleration?

**EDIT**:

Adding some code:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
  super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
  mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
  canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

Comment: kindly show some code. how do you show the content ? do you update a bitmap and then show it ?